# not able to print star pattern in given patter in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am looking to solve this problem for printing * start pattern in nodejs commandline. Here is the code I wrote in nodejs

```
var readlineSync = require('readline-sync');

const input = readlineSync.question('Enter a number')

for (var i = 0; i <= input; i = i+1){
  for(var j = 0; j <= i; j++){
    console.log('*')
    
  }
  console.log()
}
```

The output I am getting in repl.it:

```
*

*
*

*
*
*

*
*
*
*

*
*
*
*
*
```

Output expected:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

Comment: `console.log('*')` adds a newline. So now sure how you'd expact that output. Use a buffer string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`console.log` always puts data in a new line
set a string before the `j` loop, add to the string in that loop, then `console.log` that string after that loop

```js
var readlineSync = require('readline-sync');

const input = readlineSync.question('Enter a number')

for (var i = 0; i <= input; i = i+1){
  var tempStr=""
  for(var j = 0; j <= i; j++){
    tempStr+="*"
  }
  console.log(tempStr)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Console.log adds a new line, you have to create string and concat stars to that.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i = i + 1) {
  let star = "";
  for (var j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
    star += "*";
  }
  console.log(star);
}
```

You can also use the padEnd function to solve this.

```js
const n = 5;
for (var i = 1; i <= n; i = i + 1) {
  const stars = Array(i + 1).join("*");
  stars.padEnd(n);
  console.log(stars);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a working solution with the classic readline, one loop and an array:

```js
(async () => {
    const readline = require('readline');
    const rl = readline.createInterface({ input: process.stdin , output: process.stdout });

    const input = await new Promise(resolve => {
      rl.question("Enter a number ", resolve)
    })
  
  
    for (var i = 1; i <= input; i++){
      console.log(Array(i).fill('*').join(''))
    }
})()
```

Explanation:

We use readline package to read the input, we use an IIFE in order to use async await capabilities and to await on user input which is resolved in the input variable thanks to await.

Then we create an array with the loop length which we fill of stars and join to create the string to console.log.

Here is another way without creating an array on each iteration:

```js
(async () => {
    const readline = require('readline');
    const rl = readline.createInterface({ input: process.stdin , output: process.stdout });

    const input = await new Promise(resolve => {
      rl.question("Enter a number ", resolve)
    })
    const arrayToFill = []
  
    for (var i = 1; i <= input; i++){
      arrayToFill[i] = '*'
      console.log(arrayToFill.join(''))
    }
})()
```

You can also use the [String.prototype.padEnd](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padEnd) method to don't work with arrays at all here is an example:

```js
(async () => {
    const readline = require('readline');
    const rl = readline.createInterface({ input: process.stdin , output: process.stdout });

    const input = await new Promise(resolve => {
      rl.question("Enter a number ", resolve)
    })

    for (var i = 1; i <= input; i++){
      console.log(''.padEnd(i,'*'))
    }
})()
```

Hope that helps!